# Trying to send email to Google through in Python, email being denied

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I'm getting a strange error when I send email through Python using SMTP.

I get an email from Mail Delivery System in my GoDaddy inbox with the error:

> [Return Code 550] sid: Xtpe1o00e3l0Tyx01 :: 5.7.1 more information. ye4si18523263pbb.103 - gsmtp

For reference, the script looks like:

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtpout.secureserver.net', 465)

print("Logging in: ")
server.login("username", "password")

subject = "This is a test email!"
msg = "Sample email message"
text = 'Subject: %s\n\n%s' % (subject, msg)
fromaddr = "fromemail"
toaddr = "toemail"
print("Sending email...")
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

But I believe my error has nothing to do with the code, but with Google blocking the email.

Comment: The error message should have a link to the specific error, like https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596. Even if that link doesn't answer the question for you, nobody can solve your problem without knowing which particular 550 you got.

Comment: BTW, this is exactly why you should always copy and paste complete error messages instead of just a snippet or a description; if you don't know how to even begin to debug a problem, you probably don't know what part of the error message is useful.

Comment: Did the error email have the original email attached? If so, examine that email and confirm that it has "To:", "From:", "Date:", and "Message-ID:" headers.

Comment: @abarnert what I posted was the entire error message I received.

Comment: @Robᵩ interestingly enough, the email was attached, and the 'To:' and 'From:' fields were both blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning: Wild guess from incomplete data**

Your email is being rejected as spam. Ensure your email is RFC2822-compliant. Quoting [the standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt):

> > The only required header fields are the origination date field and
> >        the originator address field(s).

In your case, add at least `From:` and `To:` to your outgoing email:

```
text = 'From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s' % (fromaddr, toaddr, subject, msg)
```

and confirm that smtplib automatically adds the `Date:` field.