# Sending email using luasocket smtp and ssl

Tags: email, ssl, lua

I have been trying to send an email using the code described in the post:

[lua send mail with gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070623/lua-send-mail-with-gmail-account)

The code by [Michal Kottman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221509/michal-kottman) is repeated below:

```
-- Michal Kottman, 2011, public domain
local socket = require 'socket'
local smtp = require 'socket.smtp'
local ssl = require 'ssl'
local https = require 'ssl.https'
local ltn12 = require 'ltn12'

function sslCreate()
    local sock = socket.tcp()
    return setmetatable({
        connect = function(_, host, port)
            local r, e = sock:connect(host, port)
            if not r then return r, e end
            sock = ssl.wrap(sock, {mode='client', protocol='tlsv1'})
            return sock:dohandshake()
        end
    }, {
        __index = function(t,n)
            return function(_, ...)
                return sock[n](sock, ...)
            end
        end
    })
end

function sendMessage(subject, body)
    local msg = {
        headers = {
            to = 'Your Target <target email>',
            subject = subject
        },
        body = body
    }

    local ok, err = smtp.send {
        from = '<your email>',
        rcpt = '<target email>',
        source = smtp.message(msg),
        user = 'username',
        password = 'password',
        server = 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port = 465,
        create = sslCreate
    }
    if not ok then
        print("Mail send failed", err) -- better error handling required
    end
end
```

The code works good if I send something from gmail. But when I use godaddy smtp server which is smtpout.secureserver.net (same port) it fails to send the message. I just get error code 550. 
       Please can anyone help me figure out how to make this work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked thanks to this post:

[Trying to send email to Google through in Python, email being denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002795/trying-to-send-email-to-google-through-godaddy-in-python-email-being-denied)

I just changed the code to add the from field in the headers table like this:

```
-- Michal Kottman, 2011, public domain
local socket = require 'socket'
local smtp = require 'socket.smtp'
local ssl = require 'ssl'
local https = require 'ssl.https'
local ltn12 = require 'ltn12'

function sslCreate()
    local sock = socket.tcp()
    return setmetatable({
        connect = function(_, host, port)
            local r, e = sock:connect(host, port)
            if not r then return r, e end
            sock = ssl.wrap(sock, {mode='client', protocol='tlsv1'})
            return sock:dohandshake()
        end
    }, {
        __index = function(t,n)
            return function(_, ...)
                return sock[n](sock, ...)
            end
        end
    })
end

function sendMessage(subject, body)
    local msg = {
        headers = {
            from = "<your email>",
            to = 'Your Target <target email>',
            subject = subject
        },
        body = body
    }

    local ok, err = smtp.send {
        from = '<your email>',
        rcpt = '<target email>',
        source = smtp.message(msg),
        user = 'username',
        password = 'password',
        server = 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port = 465,
        create = sslCreate
    }
    if not ok then
        print("Mail send failed", err) -- better error handling required
    end
end
```